# What do I need to adapt a Hope Pro 4 to a Boost 141 frame?

Tags: hub, replacement

I have a 2021 Trek Roscoe 7 and I’m looking to buy a rear Hope Pro 4 hub. My Trek comes stock with a Formula DC-2241 rear hub, alloy, 6 bolt, Shimano 8/9/10 freehub, Boost141, 5mm QR. The rims are Bontrager Line 40, 28-hole, 40mm width. I’ve done some research and one person had to buy a QR141 adapter to fit a 148mm Hope Pro 4 rear hub. Is this what I need to replace my stock hub or is there an easier or better way?

Comment: Hope supply a variety of end caps to convert most of their hubs to most current fitting systems. Try emailing this question to the support team on their website, then put the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Hope HUB238 conversion kit.

It will convert Hope Pro 4 hubs to quick release. Boost Thru Axle will become QR Boost 141mm. 142mm Thru Axle will become standard QR 135mm.

Description taken from an online Shop:

- Converts Hope Pro 4 BOOST hub (148mm) to QR Boost (141mm)
- Converts Hope Pro 4 142mm to QR (135mm)